# The argument type 'void Function(AttendanceState?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)?'

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button

I am making AttendanceApp in flutter.Here is the code.

```
class RadioButtonWithText extends StatelessWidget {
  const RadioButtonWithText({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.value,
    required this.groupValue,
    required this.onChanged,
  });
  final String text;
  final Object value;
  final Object? groupValue;
  final void Function(Object?)? onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(text),
      leading: Radio(
        value: value,
        groupValue: groupValue,
        onChanged: onChanged,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
RadioButtonWithText(
 text: AttendanceState.tardy.displayState,
 value: AttendanceState.tardy,
 groupValue: _attendanceState,
 onChanged: (AttendanceState? value) {
   _attendanceState.value = value;
 },
),
```

but when I set RadioButtonWithText onChanged. I got some error.

```
 onChanged: (AttendanceState? value) {
   _attendanceState.value = value;
 },
```

`The argument type 'void Function(AttendanceState?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)?'.`

I have eliminated the error by making the Object? dynamic, but I don't think it is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```dart
class RadioButtonWithText extends StatelessWidget {
  const RadioButtonWithText({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.value,
    required this.groupValue,
    required this.onChanged,
  });
  final String text;
  final Object value;
  final Object? groupValue;
  final void Function(AttendanceState?)? onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(text),
      leading: Radio(
        value: value,
        groupValue: groupValue,
        onChanged: onChanged,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's work but Is it safe to use dynamic?

Comment: Does the value have to be `AttendanceState`? If yes, please let me know and I will edit my answer. If not, you should use `dynamic`

Comment: Yes, I want to use AttendanceState.